# Qt:QImage thread safety issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I would like to load several images from binary file in a worker thread and paint the result out in a widget. 
According to the doc, QPixMap cannot be used outside the GUI thread.
So I am thinking of using QImage in the following way:

```
//in worker thread:
  ...
  mutex.lock()
  Images.append(QImage::fromData(data));//Images is a QList<QImage>
  mutex.lock()
  ...

//in GUI thread Widget's paint event:
  ...
  mutex.lock()
  foreach(QImage tmp, Images)
  {
    //paint tmp out
    painter->drawImage...
  }
  mutex.lock()
  ...
```

Is it thread safe?

Comment: Sure, if you mean to `lock` then `unlock` instead of `lock` twice. I prefer RAII types like `QMutexLocker` or `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: You could send over the QImage via a queued signal slot connection to avoid the manual synchronization. (the QImage is implicitly shared so the copy is cheap)